Induction wok alternative for gas wok?
I’m starting a food trailer business and considering an induction wok instead of a traditional gas wok for preparing fried rice. The benefits—such as space-saving, enhanced safety, and avoiding the need to carry gas cylinders—are appealing. However, I’d like input on whether induction can truly replace gas for this purpose. If it’s viable, I would also appreciate recommendations for reliable induction wok sets for food trailer.

One concern with induction over gas is the loss of "wok hei", the typical wok flavour developed by tossing the food in the wok over an open gas flame. A blowtorch can somewhat reproduce this, but it's not a substitute for the real deal, see https://www.seriouseats.com/hei-now-youre-a-wok-star-a-fiery-hack-for-stir-frying-at-home

CookTek has an Iinduction cooktop specifically for round wok bottoms, but they are too niche for my needs. Wok cooking and getting "wok hei" is the only reason that I'm holding onto my gas stove. Induction meets all of my other cooking needs. ‍♂️ I'm curious what you ultimately decide.
